# Issue with cordova hybrid application using appium

Tags: appium

I am testing cordova hybrid application using appium.I am able to switch to "webview" using window_handles.last. But issue is , i am not able to find the element using find_element method. 
@driver.find_element(:class_name,'loginBtn').click. I am getting below error.

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)

Answer (score 0):

Which API platform version are you using?

I was receiving the same error while testing on an ASUS tablet running Android 4.2.1 (API 17), but then I switched to a Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro (4.4.2, API 19) and a Nexus 7 (5.02, API 21) and was able to select WebElements.

KitKat introduced remote debugging of WebViews, which could be why this error only appears on prior versions.